# difference between compiler and compiler driver in LLVM?

Tags: compiler-construction, llvm

Can someone explain what is the difference between compiler and compiler driver in LLVM?

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 14):

### Simply put

the `compiler` is a part of the integral compilation process; the `compiler driver` is the concatenation and manager of the compilation process.

But we usually confuse these two concepts and call them compiler.

### In fact

A compiler consists of multiple parts, and when a program source is compiled into an executable, it goes through a number of different steps.
`Source code -> preprocessing -> compilation -> assembly -> linking`.
Different compiler components are in charge of different stages.

For example, compilation is in charge of the `Compiler` (`cc1` for c, `cc1plus` for cxx, `cc1obj` for Objective-C etc.) **(where `cc1`, `cc1plus`, `cc1obj`, etc. are really the `Compilers`. The `Compiler` uses source code as inputs and output as assembly code).**
`as` is responsible for transforming assembly code to binary code, and the `ld` is responsible for linking.

In order to facilitate the process, we usually only use
`clang hello.c -o hello` 
to complete the construction of a c source to the final executable.
But in fact, in this process, `clang` is the ***`compiler driver`***, which connects the entire compilation process in an automated way. It does a lot of work, it calls every tool in the compiler with the appropriate parameters and order, and eventually produces an executable file.

### Specifically

the detailed parameters of the `clang hello.c -o hello` command can be seen by command `clang hello.c -o hello -v`

And on my terminal, it displays:

```
clang version 8.0.0 (tags/RELEASE_800/final)
Target: x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /home/huangshaomang/research/LLVM/ollvmsimon/build/bin

 "/home/huangshaomang/research/LLVM/build/bin/clang-8" "-cc1" "-triple" "x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu" "-emit-obj" "-mrelax-all" "-disable-free" "-main-file-name" "hello.c" "-mrelocation-model" "static" "-mthread-model" "posix" "-mdisable-fp-elim" "-fmath-errno" "-masm-verbose" "-mconstructor-aliases" "-munwind-tables" "-fuse-init-array" "-target-cpu" "x86-64" "-dwarf-column-info" "-debugger-tuning=gdb" "-resource-dir" "/home/huangshaomang/research/LLVM/build/lib/clang/8.0.0" "-internal-isystem" "/usr/local/include" "-internal-isystem" "/home/huangshaomang/research/LLVM/build/lib/clang/8.0.0/include" "-internal-externc-isystem" "/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu" "-internal-externc-isystem" "/include" "-internal-externc-isystem" "/usr/include" "-fdebug-compilation-dir" "/home/huangshaomang/research/linker_loader/test_constructor" "-ferror-limit" "19" "-fmessage-length" "233" "-fobjc-runtime=gcc" "-fdiagnostics-show-option" "-fcolor-diagnostics" "-o" "/tmp/hello-5168fe.o" "-x" "c" "hello.c" "-faddrsig"

 "/usr/bin/ld" "-z" "relro" "--hash-style=gnu" "--eh-frame-hdr" "-m" "elf_x86_64" "-dynamic-linker" "/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2" "-o" "hello" "/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5.4.0/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o" "/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5.4.0/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/crti.o" "/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5.4.0/crtbegin.o" "-L/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5.4.0" "-L/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5.4.0/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu" "-L/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu" "-L/lib/../lib64" "-L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu" "-L/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5.4.0/../../.." "-L/home/huangshaomang/research/LLVM/build/bin/../lib" "-L/lib" "-L/usr/lib" "/tmp/hello-5168fe.o" "-lgcc" "--as-needed" "-lgcc_s" "--no-as-needed" "-lc" "-lgcc" "--as-needed" "-lgcc_s" "--no-as-needed" "/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5.4.0/crtend.o" "/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5.4.0/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/crtn.o"
```

It is clear, `clang`(the `compiler driver`) called two tools (`cc1`(the `Compiler`) and `ld`(the `linker`)) in turn with very complex parameters.

Also, In the following links, llvm-project used the term 'compiler driver', which may help you understand it better.

https://llvm.org/docs/HowToCrossCompileLLVM.html
https://llvm.org/docs/LinkTimeOptimization.html

Answer (score 3):

I guess, **compiler** refers to compiler as a whole, while **compiler driver** corresponds to logic that drives compilation pipeline. Driver task is to call right tools for various files (for example, `clang` calls `cc1` for C/C++ sources, `ld` for object files, etc.) and to set proper flags for them.

Answer (score 3):

In llvm, we always use the clang. I will explain your question using clang as an example.

When you input "clang" to command line, it is the compiler driver. The compiler driver has many options, these options will decide which compiler component will be called. For example: clang -cc1 is the frontend, clang is the driver. The driver invokes the frontend with options appropriate for your system.

So, I think the compiler driver drivers the compiler components, to make them working together.